# Eslint disallow a built-in global function?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a rule to disable specific built-in JS functions? E.g. I want to disable `parseFloat` because there's almost never cases where `parseFloat` is better than unary `+`.

Comment: I would argue that `parseFloat` is way more explicit…!

Comment: @deceze I prefer to use the `Number` function for conversion `Number("42") //42`. It's explicit and you can very easily pass it around, too `["1", "2", "3"].map(Number)`. With that said, I still think `parseFloat` is useful, since it doesn't just do a conversion on the whole string but you can use it to extract a number from be beginning, e.g., `parseFloat("3.50 USD") //3.5`, while `Number` or `+` would return `NaN`, so you'd have to write more unneeded code to extract the number from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [no-restricted-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals):

> Disallowing usage of specific global variables can be useful if you want to allow a set of global variables by enabling an environment, but still want to disallow some of those.
>
> This rule allows you to specify global variable names that you don’t want to use in your application.

Example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-globals": ["parseFloat"]
  }
}
```

Or, for a more descriptive warning:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-globals": [
      "error",
      {
        "name": "parseFloat",
        "message": "Use + instead."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this for `JSON.stringify`. Or some other eslint rule?